# Coleta do value via PHP e JSon

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

Possuo um select onde os dados estão em uma base JSON que estão disponibilizados no link:

https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978.js[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A opção de select funciona normalmente ,ou seja , os dados aparecem no campo designado porém não consigo resgatar o valor e salvar no banco. Ao enviar os valores são salvos como 0. Demais campos enviados no formulário são salvos normalmente . Alguém sabe como posso coletar o value disponibilizado via JSON e salvar no banco de dados ? Para salvar os dados estou utilizando o PHP  .

Parte HTML

```
        <div class="form-row ">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3  mb-3 ">
                <label >Estado </label>
                   <Select class="form-control" name="Estado" ID="Estado"  required>
                      <option selected value=""></option>
                  </Select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb-3 ">
                <label >Cidade</label>
                <Select class="form-control" name="Cidade" ID="Cidade"  required>
                      <option selected value=""></option>
                  </Select>
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    carregar_json('Estado');
    function carregar_json(id, cidade_id){
        var html = '';

        $.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/letanure/3012978/raw/36fc21d9e2fc45c078e0e0e07cce3c81965db8f9/estados-cidades.json', function(data){
            html += '<option>Selecionar '+ id +'</option>';
            console.log(data);
            if(id == 'Estado' && cidade_id == null){
                for(var i = 0; i < data.estados.length; i++){
                    html += '<option value='+ data.estados[i].sigla +'>'+ data.estados[i].nome+'</option>';

                }
            }else{
                for(var i = 0; i < data.estados.length; i++){
                    if(data.estados[i].sigla == cidade_id){
                        for(var j = 0; j < data.estados[i].cidades.length; j++){
                            html += '<option value='+ data.estados[i].sigla +'>'+data.estados[i].cidades[j]+ '</option>';

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $('#'+id).html(html);

        });

    }

    $(document).on('change', '#Estado', function(){
        var cidade_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(cidade_id);
        if(cidade_id != null){
            carregar_json('Cidade', cidade_id);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: O Arquivo Json contém uma lista de cidades e estados do Brasil no seguinte formato : 

{
  "estados": [
    {
      "sigla": "AC",
      "nome": "Acre",
      "cidades": [
        "Acrelândia",
        "Assis Brasil",
Etc ..

Link : https://gist.github.com/letanure/3012978

Comment: Parece que falta colocar o value gerado dinamicamente entre aspas (") `html += '<option value="'+ data.estados[i].sigla +'">'`.

Comment: A princípio o único problema que eu encontrei é que o `values` das cidades estão com a `uf` do estado, isso deve ser alterado para o nome da cidade ou código IBGE. Sobre a inserção na base, adicione o código que faz esse envio dos dados

Comment: Segue parte do código . Acredito que este não seja a questão pois todos os dados encaminhados são registrados .  

if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar_usuario'])){ 
            $Estado= $_POST['Estado'];
            $Cidade= $_POST['Cidade'];
 $sql ="INSERT INTO tabela (Estado,Cidade VALUES '$Estado','$Cidade')";

Comment: Benilson , Fiz as alterações porém o resultado continua sendo enviado em branco para o banco